# SP Foundation LAN OK but KO through internet

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have just created a small SharePoint Foundation 2010 farm.
* Active directory (domain = MyDomain.local)
* SQL Server (member of MyDomain.local)
* Web front end (member of MyDomain.local)

Everything works fine when on LAN, but when trying to acces through internet with public domain name (MyPublicDomain.com), there is no response : I am correctly prompted to set my credentials, the farm seems to work, but the welcome page is never displayed.

Do you have any idea of what is occurring ?

In the logs, some times, I have an error mentionning that I a m not allowed to access an iis config file, and sometimes, I do not have any error.

Please heeeeeelp :)

thank you everyone for any help and sorry for my ugly poor written english

regards,
Laurent MONDEIL

Answer (score 1):

- Actually,
  my WebApplication's default zone'url is http://sp.mypublicdomain.com and I have no other zones declared
  the IIS site host header is sp.mypublicdomain.com on port 80
- When you say "Check that you end up on the correct IIS web site", what do you mean ? How do I check this ?
- Firewall is configured to allow trafic on ports 80 and 443 for World Wied Web Services

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your Alternative access mapping (under Application Management). You need to set one up for your public address. you might need to configure Host headers in the IIS too.
- Check that you end up on the correct IIS web site.
- Also verify that you have your port 80/443 in the firewall.

Comment: In IIS add a index.html page to the root folder of the IIS Default Site on port 80 (Not the SharePoint created web site on port 80), add some content in it just so that you know that it's that file you will receive. And then try to access you site from the public URL. If you get the response of the HTML file you just created you know that your are at the wrong web site and can configure IISfrom that.

Comment: I have made a try.

Comment: Actually, the server seems to give the right page of the right site (http://sp.mypublicdomain.com/SitePages/Accueil.aspx. But the browser still tries to get information and no page is displayed.

Comment: so what happens when you go to sp.mypublicdomain.com?

Comment: I am prompted to give login and password, then infinite loop but destination url in bowser url bar is correct ...

Comment: That means your trying to access something that the user your using don't have access to. I'm just guessing your trying to access the wrong website. So what happens if you stop the Default Website in IIS. Not the SharePoint - 80 (Just guessing the sharepoint site name) do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes. there seem to be a problem on my IIS routing

Comment: I think you haven't correctly configured your host header settings in IIS. But without knowing more about your environment or how you are trying to access it, i can only tell you to set your host header to the external IP number of your server and not all unassigned, also be careful what you have set your default website to.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be a security problem : when I put an html file on my virtual directory, it works, but when I put asp.net files assemblies and so on, it only works on local network. is it a IIS configuration problem, a Firewall problem or a DNS problem ?

Comment: I don't know what your virtual directory is. I don't even know if your talking about your SharePoint web site or if your talking about your Default Web site in IIS...

Comment: I'm not talking about SharePoint any more : the final goal is to get my SharePoint foundation working, but my investigations seem to demonstrate that SharePoint is not the original problem - Other simple applications working with databases don't seem to work either. I have tried (on the same application, and so on the same virtual directory) to define a simple static page (html) than works outside LAN - simple aspx page also works. but complex applications (such as SharePoint or Orchard) don't work.

Comment: Your issue is still what i belive is what i said from the start. When your accessing your external URL your redirected to the Default Website on port 80 in IIS, Not to your SharePoint website on port 80. ASP.Net doesn't have any setting to stop working when accessing an ASP.Net application from an external address and work only for local machine. So no SharePoint is not the problem, but your configuration is...